# What does "Wie stark ist nicht dein Zauberton" mean?

Tags: meaning

Google Translate says this means "How strong is not your magic!" This does not make any sense. Without *nicht*, though, it makes sense. Could anyone tell me what usage this is?

This is the title of an aria from Mozart's opera "Die Zauberflöte" (The Magic Flute).

Comment: Might be some kind of artistic license.

Comment: So, what is the meaning?

Comment: This is more or less the same thing as "Your magic is strong, isn't it?", just in poetic German.

Comment: I really start wondering about the way German seems to be taught in... where ever. Many contributors here have been asking recently for help with admittedly difficult sentences. But the point is: these sentences are always taken from very high-level works of art; usually they have some expression that is used exclusively and uniquely in this one and single piece of literature; they are of no relevance for learning German in any practical way. - Teachers should offer their students tasks relevant for everyday use first.

Answer (score 7):

The word *nicht* is not only used to negate a statement (translating to *not* in English), but it can also be used to emphasize a statement<sup>1</sup>. Typical examples are

> Was es *nicht* alles gibt!
>
> Was du *nicht* sagst!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>See meaning 3. of „nicht“, provided by the Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/nicht, accessed 11.11.2017.</sup>

Comment: One should add: "Was Lehrer im Deutschunterreicht für Nichtmuttersprachler *nicht* für bescheuerte Textbeispiele auswählen!"

Comment: "Was du nicht sagst!" is paralleled by the (by now rather old fashioned) "You don't say!"

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a question, it's an exclamation meaning "How strong your magic is!".

Since the point of the utterance is to draw attention to the *strength* of the device, it's obvious the speaker thinks it is great, not small. Therefore  makes little difference whether you use a negation or not in this construction, and at the time this was written (around 1790) it was customary to use one.

(Compare "Is this great, or what?" with "Isn't this great?" - the meaning is the same with or without "not".)

Answer (score 4):

In the old times one would have looked into the booklet (typically in three or four languages), to find:

> How powerful is your magic music,/
>   sweet flute, for when you sound/
>   even wild beasts feel joy.

Full English text to be found [here](http://www.murashev.com/opera/Die_Zauberfl%C3%B6te_libretto_English_Act_1)